Can't the loss function be used as a fitness function?
Can't the loss function used in backpropagation be used as a fitness function in an evolutionary algorithm?

Why are you asking this question? Can you provide more context?

@nbro Personally, I think evolution is better than backpropagation.

Ok, and? How does that motivate your question?

@nbro I didn't know how to create a fitness function, so I was wondering if I could use an already existing loss function.

So, how do you know that evolution is better than backpropagation, if you don't even know what a fitness function is? Evolution can also mean different things. Are you talking about biological evolution or evolutionary algorithms? There are also many evolutionary algorithms.

@nbro Backpropagation causes forgetting

It definitely can.  It took a bit but I found discussion on NEAT for supervised classification.
But for the record, evolutionary algorithms are a lot more interesting on problems which are not differentiable.  They tend to be computationally expensive if you already know a reasonable algorithm (backprop).

A loss function can be simply converted into a fitness function or a reward function by negating it.
Or in evolutionary algorithms it's also easy to use the loss function as is, then when applying selection process, select the lowest scoring individuals values from the population instead of the highest.
If the loss function has been defined to work with gradient-based methods on complex problems (e.g. image recognition), then those gradient based methods will usually significantly outperform evolution-inspired algorithms. From comments it appears you would like to explore this difference yourself.
